# How to alternate elements from 2 different list

Tags: php, arrays

Through a foreach of an array I got a list of names and through another foreach on the same I got a list of ranks. Now if I print them I obtain first the list of names and them the list of ranks, but I want to alternate them like:

First name
first rank
second name
second rank

Comment: It will be easier to help if you provide some code sample

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood you, it sounds like you're iterating the same array to get the separate name and rank arrays.

Why not just iterate the original array to list the names and ranks together?

```
foreach ($original_array as $person) {
    echo "$person[name]: $person[rank]";
}
```